# Computing a series with large numbers : Python

Tags: python, series, largenumber

Note: Corrected the silly mistake pointed out in the line `for i in xrange(10000)`

I am writing a code for calculating and plotting MittagLeffler functions using a series expansion,

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from decimal import Decimal
import pylab as plt
from math import gamma


def MLf(x,a):
    mlf = Decimal(0)
    X = (x)
    term = Decimal(0)
    for j in xrange(100):
        term = Decimal((-1)**j*(X**(j*a)))/Decimal(gamma(a*j+1))
        mlf = Decimal( term + mlf )
    return mlf


x = np.arange(0,1000,0.1)
y = np.arange(0,1000,0.1)

for i in xrange(10000):
    y[i] = MLf(x[i],1)


plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

However, the calculation of the function (MLf) seems to fail for x>30.

This is likely due to the divergence of series due to the limited number of iterations. But, if I increase the number of iterations, it shows a math range error.

Here is the snippet of values, showing where it starts diverging

```
x        y 
40.8 -10.9164990034 
40.9 -12.2457070844 
41.0 -17.4658523232 
41.1 -10.8310002768 
41.2 -10.5217830371 
41.3 -13.9001627961 
41.4 -30.8944707201
```

Comment: You're re-using `x` and `y` — make that last loop go to 10000 and you won't see the discontinuity.

Comment: @goyo I think he's doing `plt.xlim(0,12); plt.ylim(0,1.4)` or similar.

Comment: I think it's probably a better idea to post new questions, rather than change an existing question. If you don't, we'll need to delete these comments and my other answer otherwise this thread will make no sense.

Comment: @user35962 I posted a question about this instability [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645381/instability-in-mittag-leffler-function-using-numpy), using a simplified version of your function.

Comment: @kwinkunks Thank you so much. I have accepted your answer here

Comment: although, I would like to emphasize somewhere that I am interested in values of 0 < a  < 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-using `x` and `y` at the end, but only replacing indices up to 100. So do this at the end and it works:

```
for i in range(10000):  # Or use xrange in Python 2.7
    y[i] = MLf(x[i], 1)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Or make different arrays for this part.

Comment: That's a horrible mistake I looked over, thanks for pointing out! I will check it out now!

Comment: Ok, now that I have corrected it, the series doesn't converge for 100 number iterations I have used in function MLf. But then, increasing the iterations gives me math error. I will edit the question in a while