# Instability in Mittag-Leffler function using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

In trying to reproduce [the plot on Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mittag-LefflerFunction.html), and in trying to help with [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48643475/computing-a-series-with-large-numbers-python), I ran into some numerical instability I don't understand:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import gamma

def MLf(z, a):
    """Mittag-Leffler function
    """
    k = np.arange(100).reshape(-1, 1)
    E = z**k / gamma(a*k + 1)
    return np.sum(E, axis=0)

x = np.arange(-50, 10, 0.1)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
for i in range(5):
    plt.plot(x, MLf(x, i), label="alpha = "+str(i))
plt.legend()
plt.ylim(-5, 5); plt.xlim(-55, 15); plt.grid()
```

You can see the instability best in the orange line where `a = 1`, starting at about `x = -35`, but there's a problem with `a = 0` (blue line) too. Changing the number of terms to sum (i.e. `j`) changes the `x` at which the instability occurs.

What's going on? How can I avoid this?

[image: Mittag-Leffler function plot]

Comment: Interesting... I'm rather surprised that the other curves look fine (for the exception of a=0 which fails more than for a=1). I guess the higher order ones don't show weird behavior because they converge quickly (the denominator grows huge very quickly). Sadly I don't have a better suggestion than to find an alternative representation for the cases of `a={0,1}' that shows better stability. What's a nice representation for maths is not necessarily a good one for computation.

Comment: Yes, this is quite interesting! I tried a log-space representation using `gammaln` and breaking out the even and odd cases, but the curve for a=1 was even worse. There's probably a good reason, but it's beyond me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a=0, the series definition of MLf that you are using only applies when |z|<1. Indeed, when the base z is greater than 1 in absolute value, the powers `z**k` keep increasing, and the series diverges. Looking at its 100th, or another, partial sum is pointless, those sums have nothing to do with the function outside of the interval -1 < z < 1.  Just use the formula 1/(1-z) for the case a=0.

#### Case a = 1

The function is `exp(z)` and technically, it is represented by the power series `z**k / k!` for all z. But for large negative z this power series experiences catastrophic [loss of significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance): the individual terms are huge, for example, `(-40)**40/factorial(40)` is over 1e16, but their sum is tiny (`exp(-40)` is nearly zero). Since 1e16 approaches the limits of double precision, the output becomes dominated by the noise of truncating/rounding operations.

In general, evaluating polynomials by adding `c(k) * z**k` is not the best thing to do, both from the efficiency and precision standpoints. Horner's scheme is implemented in NumPy already, and using it simplifies the code:

```
k = np.arange(100)
return np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(z, 1/gamma(a*k + 1))
```

However, this is not going to save the series for exp(z), its numeric issues are beyond NumPy.

You could use `mpmath` for evaluation, gaining in accuracy (`mpmath` supports arbitrarily high precision of floating point operations) and losing in speed (no compiled code, no vectorization).

Or you could just return `exp(z)` from MLf when a=1.

#### Case 0 < a < 1

The series converges, but again with catastrophic precision loss; and now there is no explicit formula to fall back on. The aforementioned `mpmath` is one option: set really high precision (`mp.dps = 50`) and hope it's enough to sum the series. The alternative is to look for another way to compute the function.

Looking around, I found the paper ["Computation of the Mittag-Leffler function and its derivative"](https://www.academia.edu/29158050/COMPUTATION_OF_THE_MITTAG_LEFFLER_FUNCTION_E%CE%B1_%CE%B2_z_AND_ITS_DERIVATIVE) by
Rudolf Gorenflo, Joulia Loutchko & Yuri Luchko; 2002. I took formula (23) from it, and used it for negative z and 0 < a < 1.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import gamma
from scipy.integrate import quad

def MLf(z, a):
    """Mittag-Leffler function
    """
    z = np.atleast_1d(z)
    if a == 0:
        return 1/(1 - z)
    elif a == 1:
        return np.exp(z)
    elif a > 1 or all(z > 0):
        k = np.arange(100)
        return np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(z, 1/gamma(a*k + 1))

    # a helper for tricky case, from Gorenflo, Loutchko & Luchko
    def _MLf(z, a):
        if z < 0:
            f = lambda x: (np.exp(-x*(-z)**(1/a)) * x**(a-1)*np.sin(np.pi*a)
                          / (x**(2*a) + 2*x**a*np.cos(np.pi*a) + 1))
            return 1/np.pi * quad(f, 0, np.inf)[0]
        elif z == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return MLf(z, a)
    return np.vectorize(_MLf)(z, a)
    

x = np.arange(-50, 10, 0.1)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
for i in range(1, 5):
    plt.plot(x, MLf(x, i/3), label="alpha = "+str(i/3))
plt.legend()
plt.ylim(-5, 5); plt.xlim(-55, 15); plt.grid()
```

No numerical issues here.

[image: plot]

Comment: What do you think about the case of 0 < a < 1? How do I improve it in that case? - OP of the related post.

Comment: @if....: In case I want it for an argument raised to some power, can I just replace here - `np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(-z**a, 1/gamma(a*k + 1))`

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python package implementation based on a better algorithm, which is more precise and does not have the numerical instabilities shown in the OP; it's available at https://pypi.org/project/numfracpy/

It is based on Laplace transform and integration along an optimal path. The details are in the paper by Garrappa, Roberto, and Marina Popolizio. “Fast Methods for the Computation of the Mittag-Leffler Function.” In [Handbook of Fractional Calculus with Applications](https://dokumen.pub/handbook-of-fractional-calculus-with-applications-basic-theory-de-gruyter-reference-1-1nbsped-3110570815-9783110570816.html) | Volume 3: Numerical Methods, 329–46. De Gruyter, 2019. https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110571684-013. This is a great and more efficient improvement on the paper by Gorenflo et al. shown in the the best answer above.

There was a dead link in the reply selected as best, which I updated and added here as well: Gorenflo, Rudolf. “[COMPUTATION OF THE MITTAG-LEFFLER FUNCTION Eα,β(z) AND ITS DERIVATIVE.](https://www.academia.edu/29158050/COMPUTATION_OF_THE_MITTAG_LEFFLER_FUNCTION_E%CE%B1_%CE%B2_z_AND_ITS_DERIVATIVE.)” Fractional Calculus and Applied Analysis, January 1, 2002. Remember that the latter is prone to numerical problems.